# An alternative (cheaper) option than offering towel service at the gym

Tags: substitute-tool, efficiency, laundry, office

We have just got a gym facility at my work, however, we do not currently offer towel service as it is quite expensive.

Does anyone know of any alternatives to offering this service? For example, a swimsuit spinner for towels that is cheaper in the long run...?

I would really appreciate any suggestions that you all have!

Kind regards,

Comment: Towel service isn't permitted by law in my state. I take my own towel to the gym, put it in a plastic beach bag, then spin it in the washing machine and hang it on the shower bar at home. Nothing as complicated as a "life hack" is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can give every employee 2 or 3 towels for free. The catch is that they have to wash them themselves, and they have to remember to bring them to the gym. Most employees will see the gift as generous, and although it may be a large one-time expense for the company, it's a lot cheaper than washing all those towels every day or week.

EDIT:

To keep your equipment clean/dry when the members who don't bring a towel, also provide paper towels and antibacterial spray. My gym does that: paper towels for the equipment, terrycloth towels for the people.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need towel service at all? Why not just ask employees to bring their own towels if they want to use gym and take them back home to wash.

You actually didnt't consider gym shoes service, t-shirt service and shorts service, so everyone who's using the gym brings his own. Did you?  What's the difference for towels?

So answering your questions: Instead of thinking about [towel service which is always expensive and difficult to manage](https://www.athleticbusiness.com/fitness-training/towels-customer-service-or-money-pit.html) think about spending that money on extending gym equipment which in my opinion will have better impact on "customer satisfaction".

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an ad about a paper towel (kitchen towel) that was said to be so absorbent that, at a pinch, it could be used to towel off after a shower.

([This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gO-ORzApIdA) might be the ad. #include "disclaimer.h" - commercial product.)

I've tried it. Given the right paper towel, it works. It's not as good as a proper towel service, but it's a pretty cheap life hack that does the job. Bonus: it's paper, so in theory at least, it's recyclable.

There are even commercial solutions surrounding single-use towels based on similar principles. (Here's [one](http://www.easydry.com.au/). #include "disclaimer.h" - commercial product.) I've used these while camping. They are much larger sheets, purpose-designed so probably not a life-hack, but they might be a useful alternative to providing proper towels in a gym.